# How to wait in loop till the series of API calls one inside another is completed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach

I am stuck in a situation in typescript.

I have a `forEach` loop in which an API call method is executed `methodOne()`; inside this method, another API call to `methodTwo()` is executed [sequentially].

Now my requirement is that the `forEach` loop should wait until both the API calls are executed and then after this, `forEach` should go for its next iteration.

Code flow looks like this:

```
list.forEach(item => {
    methodOne(item);
})

methodOne(){
    methodTwo();
}

methodTwo(){
    //some code..
}
```

**Note**: I am not using any `async, await, Promise or Observables` in the API call

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use async, await... This is exactly what you need...

Comment: If you're not using any async logic in your API calls, all your code is synchronous and your code is already doing what you want. However, if you're making a network request in javascript it is asynchronous

Comment: @LotteLemmens the reason was i didnt know how to use that in javascript, i have never done it before

Comment: @spirift I know api call are asynchronous but it works without async and await. now i know the concept and usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that asynchronous functions (both `.then()` & `async/await`) won't work inside `forEach`
**ALSO** `.then()` approach won't work in neither `forEach` or `for` loops.

To run an asynchronous function inside a loop you need to use the `async/await` approach inside either a `for` loop or a [Recursion Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

In the following example, we're gonna use the `async/await` approach inside a `for` loop.

```js
const list = ['firstItem', 'secondeItem', 'lastItem'];

// First method
// use `i` parameter to check in which index the method was called
function methodOne(i: string): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Make the first API call at index ${i}`);
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}


// Second method
// use `i` parameter to check in which index the method was called
function methodTwo(i: string): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Make the second API call at index ${i}`);
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}

// run both methods sequentially inside a `for` loop
async function runMethodOneAndMethodTwoInsideLoop (): Promise<void> {
    for (let i in list) {
        await methodOne(i);
        await methodTwo(i);
    }
}

runMethodOneAndMethodTwoInsideLoop();
```

To call `methodTwo` inside `methodOne` (which I don't recommend) you can use the following example.

```js
const list = ['firstItem', 'secondeItem', 'lastItem'];

// First method
// use `i` parameter to check in which index the method was called
function methodOne(i: string): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            console.log(`Make the first API call at index ${i}`);
            await methodTwo(i);
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}


// Second method
// use `i` parameter to check in which index the method was called
function methodTwo(i: string): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Make the second API call at index ${i}`);
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}

// run only `methodOne` inside a `for` loop since `methodTwo` will be called inside `methodOne`
async function runMethodOneInsideLoop(): Promise<void> {
    for (let i in list) {
        await methodOne(i);
    }
}

runMethodOneInsideLoop();
```

To learn more about asynchronous functions and how to use them inside loops check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ammar-oker/ba7cf967a4e7bd269046cf45d3837311) I created.

Answer (score 1):

A! Like that! This one?

Just feed a bunch of async callbacks to `promiseChain`, and it will execute them sequentially.

```
function methodTwo() {
  // some code..
  return Promise.resolve(); // <= Or any async code
}

function methodOne(item: number) {
  return methodTwo().then(result => {
    // some code..
    return { item, result };
  });
}

async function promiseChain<T>(callbacks: (() => Promise<T>)[]) {
  var output: T[] = [];
  for (const callback of callbacks) {
    const result = await callback();
    output.push(result);
  }
  return output;
}

const list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
promiseChain(list.map(item => () => methodOne(item)))
  .then(responses => {
    // DO STUFF HERE
    const first_response = responses[0]; // Result of `methodOne(list[0])`
    const second_response = responses[1]; // Result of `methodOne(list[1])`
  });
```